# How to fix KeyError in zc.relation catalog

Tags: plone, relationship, zodb, plone-4.x

One of our sites has a broken relations catalog and I don't know how to fix it.

This is what I see in the log:

```py
2015-11-20T09:27:43 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1448018863.240.913599974037 http://www.example.com/folder/news-item/@@edit
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module z3c.form.form, line 218, in __call__
  Module collective.nitf.browser, line 64, in update
  Module plone.dexterity.browser.edit, line 62, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.fieldsets.extensible, line 59, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.patch, line 30, in GroupForm_update
  Module z3c.form.group, line 145, in update
  Module plone.app.z3cform.csrf, line 21, in execute
  Module z3c.form.action, line 98, in execute
  Module z3c.form.button, line 315, in __call__
  Module z3c.form.button, line 170, in __call__
  Module plone.dexterity.browser.edit, line 26, in handleApply
  Module z3c.form.group, line 126, in applyChanges
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module z3c.relationfield.event, line 76, in updateRelations
  Module zc.relation.catalog, line 546, in unindex
  Module zc.relation.catalog, line 556, in unindex_doc
  Module zc.relation.catalog, line 622, in _remove
KeyError: 304600783
```

I already tried the code in [The dreaded plone.relations IntId KeyError](http://www.zopatista.com/plone/2011/06/29/the-dreaded-plone-relations-intid-keyerror/), written by @martijn-pieters some years ago, but seems is no longer valid as I can't find any interfaces named `IComplexRelationshipContainer`.

Any hints?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290361/how-to-clean-up-old-interfaces-on-zc-relation-catalog. It shows how to get the relations in a more recent version of plone. You should be able to remove the broken `RelationValue` by setting it to `None` + notify the catalog if necessary, that the relations has been removed.

Comment: I tried that code before with no luck, it fails with an error also.

Answer (score 1):

- Verify if plone.relations are installed.
- See here http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/10/bad-relationships-relationchoice-relationcatalog-and-removed-dexterity-content-in-plone, may be the solution for this problem.

Eg.

```
from zope.component.hooks import setSite
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager
from AccessControl.SecurityManager import setSecurityPolicy
from Testing.makerequest import makerequest
from Products.CMFCore.tests.base.security import PermissiveSecurityPolicy, OmnipotentUser
from zope.component import getUtility
from zope.intid.interfaces import IIntIds
from zc.relation.interfaces import ICatalog
_policy=PermissiveSecurityPolicy()
_oldpolicy=setSecurityPolicy(_policy)
newSecurityManager(None, OmnipotentUser().__of__(app.acl_users))

portal = makerequest(app['Plone'])
setSite(portal)

intids = getUtility(IIntIds)
catalog = getUtility(ICatalog)

print [x.from_object for x in sorted(catalog.findRelations({}))]
```

Comment: @cleberjsantos you are no showing here how you fixed the problem.

Comment: Only run the code snippet above and:  

1- In this case in z3c.relationfield version 0.6.3 add a comment at line 79 "addRelations(obj, event)" of event.py


2- Use the catalog’s “clear” method to remove all records with: catalog.clear()


Clearing the catalog didn’t break any of relations for the content, and everything’s now re-indexing after each content was edited and saved again.

Answer (score 1):

I think some years ago I stumpled upon something similar.

I launched this and everything worked fine later:

```
    from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
    from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
    from z3c.relationfield.event import updateRelations
    from z3c.relationfield.interfaces import IHasRelations
    from zc.relation.interfaces import ICatalog
    from zope.component import getUtility


    class View(BrowserView):
        def __call__(self):
            rcatalog = getUtility(ICatalog)
            # Clear the relation catalog to fix issues with interfaces that don't exist anymore.
            # This actually fixes the from_interfaces_flattened and to_interfaces_flattened indexes.
            rcatalog.clear()

            pc = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_catalog')
            brains = pc.searchResults(object_provides=IHasRelations.__identifier__)
            for brain in brains:
                obj = brain.getObject()
                updateRelations(obj, None)
            return "Catalog rebuilt for %s objects" % len(brains)
```

Comment: I can't tell you if this works or not because @cleberjsantos already fix it.